# Creating an Environement from requirements.txt including pip and conda

Tags: python, pip, package, conda

I have a requirements.txt created from a conda environment but it contains packages downloaded from both pip and conda. When I want to create a new environment from it with conda I get an error that some of the packages do not exist in the conda channels. Is there a way to still use this file so I don't have to download the packages one by one?

Comment: [`conda env export`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+export)

Comment: As per duplicate, and implied in comment, environments with PyPI packages cannot use `conda list --export`, but instead should use `conda env export` (YAML output).